# What's your hobby?

Tags: sentence-choice, sentence-request

**Edited:**

I have encountered lots of ways to ask someone how they pass their idle time and what they like to do as a "[pastime](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/pastime)". I'm quite confident, this term is considered as an old-fashioned term these days (at least in AE,) and many youngsters need a dictionary to look it up! 
So I will avoid using this word to ask someone how the usually spend their free time.
I need to know whether the sentence below is idiomatic and natural English or not to ask someone about their usual hobby!

- > What is your hobby?

I don't know why, but it seems to be a kind of translation from another language! If so, then how should I ask this question in a more natural way (**specially in AE**)?

Comment: You've removed your list of possible candidates! You are demoted to B-friend.

Comment: @Old Brixtonian please update your answer. I'm sorry, but I changed my question, because I thought someone found it not interesting (perhaps too long.)

Comment: :-) It's fine. I will edit it.

Comment: In the UK we would ask 'What do you do in your spare time?' Or 'Got any hobbies?'

Comment: Thank you @Old Brixtonian. Just what about "what do you do for a hobby?" Does it sound idiomatic to yoi?

Comment: It's not exactly wrong. We certainly say "What do you do for a living?", but "What do you do for a hobby" assumes everyone has a hobby: I don't think they do. (It's true that not everyone has a *job* either, but we *assume* they do.) My suggestions are the commonest in the UK, I think.

Comment: FWIW, Old Brixtonian's suggestions would also work well in the US, though many here would be likelier to say "do you have any…"  than "got any…"